# HTTP Post in ruby NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, http

I am trying to make a http post using require 'net/http' here is my request

```
token_url = 'http://www.[url].com/oauth/token'
uri = URI(token_url)
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
req.basic_auth ENV['OAUTH_ID'], ENV['OAUTH_PASSWORD']
req.set_form_data({ 'grant_type' => 'client_credentials' })
resp = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port).start {|http| http.request(req) }
JSON.parse(resp.body)['access_token']
```

I keep getting this error: `NoMethodError - undefined method 'empty?' for #<URI::HTTP:0x007fb2ed01bdf8>:`

This happens on this line "`req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)`".
any ideas why?

Comment: what is your ruby version?

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p547 (2014-05-14 revision 45962) [x86_64-darwin14.3.0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

replace

```
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
```

with

```
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
```